# Grouping Data 3 Hours after the Initial Time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, recursive-query

I need to be able to filter down a dataset to only show the first instance every 3 hours. If an instance is found, any other instances that occur up to 3 hours afterwards should be hidden.

The closes thing I've been able to find is using `date_trunc` to get the first instance each hour, but I need to hide specifically up to 3 hours after the first instance exactly.

Example Data:

```
+------------------------+-------+
|       Timestamp        | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| "2015-12-29 13:35:00"  |    65 |
| "2015-12-29 13:40:00"  |    26 |
| "2015-12-29 13:45:00"  |    80 |
| "2015-12-29 13:50:00"  |    10 |
| "2015-12-29 16:40:00"  |    76 |
| "2015-12-29 16:45:00"  |    73 |
| "2016-01-04 08:05:00"  |    87 |
| "2016-01-04 08:10:00"  |    90 |
| "2016-01-04 08:15:00"  |    52 |
| "2016-01-04 08:20:00"  |    90 |
| "2016-01-04 08:25:00"  |    23 |
| "2016-01-04 08:30:00"  |    96 |
| "2016-01-04 13:35:00"  |    53 |
| "2016-01-04 13:40:00"  |    15 |
| "2016-01-04 13:45:00"  |    85 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+------------------------+-------+
|       Timestamp        | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| "2015-12-29 13:35:00"  |    65 |
| "2015-12-29 16:40:00"  |    76 |
| "2016-01-04 08:05:00"  |    87 |
| "2016-01-04 13:30:00"  |     7 |
+------------------------+-------+

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because you need to keep track of the last picked record to identify the next one - so you can't just `group by` 3 hours intervals.

Here is one approach using a recursive cte:

```
with recursive cte(ts, value) as (
    select ts, value
    from mytable
    where ts = (select min(ts) from mytable)
    union all
    select x.*
    from (select ts from cte order by ts desc limit 1) c
    cross join lateral (
        select t.ts, t.value
        from mytable t
        where t.ts >= c.ts + interval '3' hour
        order by t.ts
        limit 1
    ) x
)
select * from cte order by ts
```

The idea is to start from the earliest record in the table, then iterate by picking the first available record that is at least 3 hours later (this assumes no duplicates in the timestamp column).

Note that `timestamp` is not a good choice for a column name, because it conflicts with a language keyword (that's a datatype). I remaned it to `ts` in the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=97e31dda61024ae56f88fcad1c1f8c26)**:

```
ts                  | value
:------------------ | ----:
2015-12-29 13:35:00 |    65
2015-12-29 16:40:00 |    76
2016-01-04 08:05:00 |    87
2016-01-04 13:35:00 |    53
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I definitely need to look into recursive functions for postgresql. Also don't worry about the name `timestamp` it was just a placeholder for easier explanation.